# OleDbException: no value given for parameters when no parameters are defined

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm encountering an OleDbException whilst running tests on an application I'm developing. The error message given is, 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

I know this question appears to have been asked several other times on this site, but in each of the cases the problem arises whilst executing an `UPDATE` command. My errors are being thrown in my `SELECT` command; to add to the confusion, I'm not even trying to use parameters, so I'm not sure what parameters it's expecting. Code for the method which raises the exception is below:

```
// Array of column letters, used in constructing the select query.
private readonly string[] COLUMN_LABELS = new string[] { "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB",
                                                        "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL",
                                                        "BM", "BN", "BO", "BP", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BU", "BV",
                                                        "BW", "BX", "BY", "BZ" }; 



 public AvailabilityReader(string spreadsheet, List<ServiceType> sundayList)
        {
            // Set up a connection to the spreadsheet.
            this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet;
            Connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format((Spreadsheet.EndsWith(".xlsx") ?
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;" :
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"), Spreadsheet));

            // Set up an adapter for the spreadsheet.
            ColumnNames = new List<string>();
            var columnString = "[E-mail Address] AS Email";
            for (int i = 1; i <= sundayList.Count; i++)
            {
                columnString += string.Format(", Column{0}", i);
                ColumnNames.Add(string.Format("Column{0}", i));
            }

            var selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [DATA$O5:{1}300]", columnString, COLUMN_LABELS[sundayList.Count - 1]), Connection);
            Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            CommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter);
            CommandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";
            CommandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

            // Obtain the table.
            var data = new DataSet();
            Adapter.Fill(data, "DATA");
            table = data.Tables["DATA"];
        }
```

The exception is raised when `Adapter.Fill(data, "DATA")` is called (Adapter being a private property of the `AvailabilityReader` class).

I honestly have no idea what's going on, but I fully expect to have missed something incredibly simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the sql after all the `string.Format` etc?

Comment: If ``sundayList`` had four elements, the resulting query would be ``SELECT [E-mail Address] AS Email, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM [DATA$O5:AV300]``

Comment: And does that work when executed directly in a query tool, rather than via your code?

Comment: Good thinking, but I'm not sure how to do that - my data source is an Excel spreadsheet as opposed to a 'proper' database. Can you suggest one that I can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually occurs when your column names are incorrect. Make sure they are consistent with the table you are getting the data from.