# C# Unable to log data onto database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, parameters

I am trying to log everytime a search is conducted on my program. The log is located on an access database. When i try to log the name of the user and computer name i receive an error and the data does not populate on my access database. Below is the code i have any support would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void logdata()
    {
        string User=""; 
        string PCName="";
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        User = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
        PCName = SystemInformation.ComputerName.ToString();


        try
        {
            string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\data.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=test";
            string cmdstr = "Insert into SearchLog(Location,SearchDate,SearchTime,User,PCName)Values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
            con.Open();

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtLocNo.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", now.ToString("d"));  
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));     
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", User);   
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", PCName); 


            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception eX)

        {

            string ErrorPrompt = "Select Ok and your search will continue";
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorPrompt, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;

        }

    }
```

Comment: If we know what is the error.

Comment: The error I get is "Syntax error into INSERT INTO statement". Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USER is a keyword in `MS-Access Jet SQL`. If you have a field or a table with that name then you should  enclose it in square brackets when passing a command text from an application.

```
string cmdstr = @"Insert into SearchLog(Location,SearchDate,SearchTime,[User],PCName)
                 Values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)";
```

I suggest, if this is possible, to change the name of that field to something different to avoid future errors of this kind.

Also keep in mind that `AddWithValue` creates the parameter with a datatype taken from the value part.
You have two fields that seems to be dates but you create a parameter of string type (ToString()).

Comment: This seemed to have fixed the problem. Would you mind elaborating as to why i need the brackets for "user"? Is user a reserved word? Thank you!

Comment: Yes is a reserved keyword.... http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are
>   marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8124103/1271037

Comment: Acces accepts parameters with the syntax @name (probably to ease the scaling to its big cousin Sql Server), however you are correct that they should be positioned correctly